# html ,javascript onclick event listener Dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to javascript/ html. I am wondering how can i get the arrow right to move the text back to the left box again? Sorry if this is a duplicate question. Kindly direct me there if there's already a similar question. Thanks in advance.

```
     <style>

.rectangle1 {
    
    height: 100px; 
    width: 150px; 
    background-color: black;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

 

.rectangle2 {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 150px; 
    background-color: grey;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    
}

 

.button {
    display: block; margin: 10px;
}

 

#input {
    color: white;
   
    
}

 

#input2 {
    color: white;
    
    
}
</style>
</head>




 <table>
    <th>
        <div class="rectangle1">
            <p id="input"></p>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th><button class="button"  onclick="myFunction2()">&lt--</button>
        <button class="button"  onclick="myFunction()">--&gt</button>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="rectangle2">
            <p id="input2"></p>
        </div>
    </th>
 </table>



<script>
function startTask() {
  var txt;
  var name = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
  if (name == null || name == "") {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
  }
  else {
    txt = name;
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = txt;
  }
  
}

function clearTask() {
    empty = ""
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = empty;
}

function myFunction() {
  
  var y = document.getElementById("input");
  document.getElementById("input2").appendChild(y);
}
function myFunction2() {
  
  var x = document.getElementById("input2");
  document.getElementById("input").appendChild(x);
  
}
</script>
</html>
```

what i have achieve,moving text from left to right

[image: Img1]

error i am getting when i try to press the <-- , trying to get the text back to rectangle 1

[image: Img2]

Comment: In your code, You are moving html element "<p></p>" directly. Try to access innerHtml attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try and see if this is what you are looking for?

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var y = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML='';
  document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML=y;
}
function myFunction2() {
  
  var x = document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML='';
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML=x;
  
}
```

EDIT:

After Lim Wen Teck asked about a solution using appendchild correctly, I modified the initial code in the question into the following :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTask() {
  var txt;
  var name = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
  if (name == null || name == "") {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
  }
  else {
    txt = name;
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = txt;
  }
  
}

function clearTask() {
    empty = ""
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = empty;
} 
function myFunction() {
  
  var y = document.getElementById("input");
  var x = document.getElementById("input2");
  var yParent = document.getElementById("input").parentElement;
  var xParent = document.getElementById("input2").parentElement;
  xParent.appendChild(y);
  yParent.appendChild(x);
} 
</script>

</head>
<body onload="startTask()">
<table>
    <th>
        <div class="rectangle1">
            <p id="input">
            sdfhdfghdfhdhgh
            </p>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th><button class="button"  onclick="myFunction()">&lt--</button>
        <button class="button"  onclick="myFunction()">--&gt</button>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="rectangle2">
            <p id="input2">
            </p>
        </div>
    </th>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The initial code in the question was moving first object under the second object with the first button click (i.e. to right), then it was trying to move the second object which is parent of the first object, under the first object. This is where the code fails. It's trying to move a parent under its child. Instead, I modified the the function into a more generic shape flow, obtaining parents of the input and input2 and swap the children between the parents. Hope this helps explain why using appenchild() in the way you did, didn't work.

Comment: Hi , it works. Thanks! But just curious, why cant i use apendchild method from right to left?

Comment: When you use appenchild (for example to right with ---> button ) , you are removing  object ("input")  from its position within DOM, and insert it under another object (input2). So  html wise it would be something  like this :  <p id="input2"><p id="input"></p> </p>   So input2 is the parent now, input is the child. with <--- button you are trying to remove the object (input2 along with all of its children including ) and insert it into input which is a child of input2. So you are trying to append a parent into its child. Use "rectangle" objects. I will add extra code for this in my answer.

Comment: Ah... no wonder there’s not a need to remove . So whenever I append to a new ID, the new ID becomes the parent?  So my understanding from you is..., before appending, everything is not a child or parent. Upon the first append, I’d”input” becomes the parent, then when I press in the button ->, input2 becomes the parent and I’d”input” becomes the child. The reason why I can’t append back to input is become it have became a child?

Comment: Yeap, pretty much so. Depending on which button you click first, there are two scenarios with your initial code. 1rst scenario :   you click  -->  button (myFunction) and input2 becomes parent of input.  2nd scenario: you click <-- button (myFunction2) and input becomes parent of input2.  So when you click a second time regardless of the button clicked, same problem happens. your code :   child.appendChild(parent).  Code tries to append the parent under its child. This is an invalid call so it fails.

Answer (score 0):

there are some fundamental issues with your code, maybe you can try this

```js
var name = null;
do {
  name = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
  name = name.trim();
  document.getElementById("input").innerText = name;
} while (!name);

const move = (fromId, toId) => {
  const from = document.getElementById(fromId);
  if (from.innerText) {
    const to = document.getElementById(toId);
    to.innerText = from.innerText;
    from.innerText = "";
  }
}

const moveLeft = () => {
  move("input2", "input");
}

const moveRight = () => {
  move("input", "input2");
}
```

```css
.rectangle>p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px dotted #333;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="rectangle">
        <p id="input"></p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="button" onclick="moveLeft()">&lt;&lt;</button>
      <button class="button" onclick="moveRight()">&gt;&gt;</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="rectangle">
        <p id="input2"></p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the guidance , i have figured out another way tho! but thanks a ton too, iit did gave me some ideas :)